# Named Credentials not retrieving end point

Tags: apex, namedcredentials, salesfoce

EDITTED DUE TO CONFUSION:

I'm trying to concatenate url param into the named credentials

`String endpoint: 'callout:XXXX' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode('PARAMS', 'utf-8');`

and im getting:
`The callout couldn't access the endpoint. You might not have the required permissions, or the named credential "XXXXPARAMS" might not exist.`

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Named Credentials and any related parameters are not populated till the very last step when a callout is made from Salesforce. This means that the `callout:XXX` merge field will not be populated with the URL endpoint in a scenario where a callout is not being made.

Answer (score 0):

`callout:named_credentials` needs to be followed by `/` or `?` if you want to add parameters (as appropriate). For example:

```
String endpoint: 'callout:XXXX?' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode('PARAMS', 'utf-8');
```

Would use the named credential `XXXX` and passing `PARAMS` as the query string. The result would look like:

```
https://mydomain.com/?PARAMS
```

Comment: THANKS!! that explains alot.
In my case i need the base name cred to be ```http://mydomain.com/token=XX&pass=YY```
and on top of that to add more params in the formula: ```&clientTK=ZZ```
So the total would look something like that: ```http://mydomain.com/token=XX&pass=YY&clientTK=ZZ```

any idea on how to do that?

Comment: @OmriCohen You should not be embedding parameters into the Named Credential itself. As I said, the only ways I know of to use NC are to use `/` or `?` after the `callout:XXXX` part. You should add any parameters you need directly on to the endpoint itself.